# Nicer Magento 2 code

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, object-manager

How do I improve this code? I use it in `ListProduct.php` to get the base price in another currency for products in `list.phtml`.

How can I do this without objectManager? Why should I not use objectManager? Will it make it slow to process the product listing?

This is from `ListProduct.php`, I call the function `getProductPrice` from `list.phtml`

```
    public function getProductBasePrice($product)
{
    $store = $product->getStore();
    $price = $product->getPrice();
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $priceCurrencyObject = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface');
    $price = $priceCurrencyObject->convert($price, $store, null);
    return $price;
}
```

Comment: do not use the object manager. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/object-manager.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usage of the ObjectManager directly defeats the purpose of Dependency Injection (DI).

Refer this [link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/object-manager.html)

> The Magento framework uses the ObjectManager to generate and inject
>   the classes declared in your constructor. Classes should not ask for
>   the ObjectManager itself as a constructor dependency.
>
> You do not call the object manager directly because the framework
>   handles this automatically. Direct use of the create function prevents
>   type validation and type hinting that a factory class provides.
>
> Object creation is also a separate responsibility that should be moved
>   to a dedicated class such as a factory or proxy. In most cases, the
>   framework generates these classes automatically during code
>   compilation.

Replace the `getProductBasePrice` method `ListProduct.php` with the below updated on and add __construct method as below.

```
public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrencyInterface
)
{
    $this->priceCurrencyInterface=$priceCurrencyInterface;
}

public function getProductBasePrice($product)
{
    $store = $product->getStore();
    $price = $product->getPrice();
    $price = $this->priceCurrencyInterface->convert($price, $store, null);
    return $price;
}
```

Also according to [PSR-2 Coding Standards](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/#42-properties),

> Property names SHOULD NOT be prefixed with a single underscore to indicate protected or private visibility.

Comment: Thank you. I have been looking for this and to understand for over a year. So much bad code all over the internet.

Comment: Btw, a small typo at "$this-_priceCurr" missing a ">"